# Checkboxes Within Modals error with checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

The code should speak for itself. I'm using the same update function for both checkboxes but the one outside the modal successfully prints whether it is checked or not but the one in the modal does not. Any idea why?

```js
$("#nonModalCheckbox").on("click", update);
$("#modalCheckbox").on("click", update);
$("#modal_show").on("click", showModal);

function showModal() {
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
}

function update() {
  console.log($(this).prop("checked"))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="nonModalCheckbox">test
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
    </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal_body">
        <div class="checkbox" id="modalCheckbox"><label><input type="checkbox">modal test</label></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="apply">Apply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="modal_show">Show Modal!</button>
```

Comment: the `#modalCheckbox` is a div, there is no chance for div to prop checked, try to drill down more level to the checkbox inside, then it will be good to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have assigned the id `modalCheckbox` to div instead of `checkbox` inside the modal. The below will work.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="modalCheckbox">modal test</label>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#nonModalCheckbox").on("click", update);
 $("#modalCheckbox").on("click", update);
 $("#modal_show").on("click", showModal);

 function showModal() {
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
 }

 function update() {
  console.log($(this).prop("checked"))
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="nonModalCheckbox">test
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body" id="modal_body">
    <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="modalCheckbox">modal test</label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="apply">Apply</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<button id="modal_show">Show Modal!</button>
```